# What means Alan Guth's Free Lunch Principle for the universe?

Tags: energy, cosmology, space-expansion, history, cosmological-inflation

Alan Guth calls the universe the [ultimate free lunch](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg15420814-800-review-the-ultimate-free-lunch/). What does he mean by this?

Does he mean that the total energy of the universe is zero? So the total energy of all particles is the negative of the total gravitational energy of these particles? If so, does this explain that the energy of the photon background radiation can be diminished by the expansion of the universe without violating energy conservation?

Comment: Hi. Not an answer to the main question, but keep in mind that in an expanding universe, the equation for "conservation of energy" is changed and not as strict as e.g. in Minkowski space, because an expanding universe does not have time translational symmetry anyway. That means, the energy in radiation (and in matter) can be diminished due to expansion, and even the energy density of "dark energy" can stay constant, without violating energy conservation anyway.